# Is it possible to set a Person or Group field through the REST API when the user is not listed on /sites/mysite/_api/web/siteusers?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, sharepoint-framework

My goal is to set a Person or Group field value on a new record to a user who may not have logged into the subsite "mysite" (and does not exist at endpoint #2 below), but who does exist at root endpoint, #1 below.

For example, John Smith exists with Id `23` at `/sites/_api/web/siteusers`, but he does not exist at all at `/sites/mysite/_api/web/siteusers`.  I want to store John Smith in a Person or Group field in a list located in `/mysite`.  John Smith has no Id for that site, however, hence the question.

I'm working with the SharePoint Online REST API using endpoints similar to these:

1 - `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/_api/web/siteusers`

2 - `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/siteusers`

3 - `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items`

I don't think it is relevant, but the context is a custom web part built with the SharePoint Framework.  The web part will be hosted on a modern page within /sites/mysite and is being tested on the tenant workbench (not local) with support files being served from my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a reference to a [`SP.User`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_User) stored on a [`SP.ListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItem) the user *must* exist in the [`SP.UserCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_UserCollection) `siteusers` of the specific [`SP.Web`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_Web) (i.e. `tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/web/subweb/_api/web/siteusers`).

The reason for this is that only the local reference to the `Id` in the `siteusers`-list is stored  when a user is referenced (using a [`SP.FieldLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldLookup)).

So you'll need to ensure the user exists on the corresponging `SP.Web`. This is done using the [`InsureUser`-Method of the `SP.Web`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebEnsureUser). I.e. by sending the correct `POST` request to `http://<site url>/_api/web/ensureuser`